# Calculate the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z)=(3z^2y, 2x^2y, 2y^2z)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Calculate the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z)=(3z^2y,  2x^2y, 2y^2z)$ coming out of the surface $S=(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that is $~2\sqrt{x^y+y^2}\leq z \leq 1+x^2+y^2.$

I thought about using the divergence theorem.
So:
$\text{Div} (F) = 2 (x^2+y^2)$.

Can anyone tell me if this procedure is correct?

$ \displaystyle 2 \iiint (x^2+y^2)~ dx~dy~dz$   $ \displaystyle = 2 \iint \left[\int_{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{1+x^2+y^2} (x^2+y^2) ~ dz\right] ~dx ~dy$
$ \displaystyle = 2 \iint (x^2+y^2)(1+x^2+y^2 -2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) ~dx ~dy $

I switched to cylindrical coordinates
$x = \rho \cos \theta, y = \rho \sin \theta $ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi], \rho \in [0,1], dx ~dy = \rho ~d\rho ~d\theta$

Comment: Yes your work is correct.

Comment: Your bounds of $\rho$ and $\theta$ are also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is correct, it is a good idea to use the divergence theorem. The integral you must compute is, in cylindrical coordinates
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{2 r}^{1+r^2} r \cdot 2r \,\,dz dr d\theta = \cdots = \frac{2\pi}{15}
$$

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: The lower bound of $z$ is incorrect. Please check the work of OP, which is correct.

Comment: It is $2 \rho$.

Comment: @AntonioTrapasso yes you are right

Comment: @MathLover Thanks, I'll edit.